# Is it possible to use regex as a case in C switch/case

Tags: c, regex, switch-statement

" This is the switch block I am trying to implement. Is this approach possible. I can find no documentation supporting this. It compiles but does not function."

```
       'switch (ch)
    {   case '[";,(){}", ]': printf("\nSEPARATOR: %c found\n", ch);
                                ch =fgetc(fin);
                                break;
        case '[_|a-zA_Z]':
                        printf("\nIDENTIFIER: ");
                        identCh[i] = ch;
                        printf("%c",identCh[i]);
                        ch = fgetc(fin);
                        while(is_letter(ch)){
                            identCh[i++] = ch;
                            ch = fgetc(fin);
                            printf("%c",identCh[i]);}
                        break;
        case '[1-9]':
                        printf("\nINTEGER: ");
                        intCh[i] = ch;
                        printf("%c",intCh[i]);
                        ch = fgetc(fin);
                        while(is_digit(ch)){
                            intCh[i++] = ch;
                            printf("%c",intCh[i]);
                            ch = fgetc(fin);}
                        break;
       // case '':    break;
        default: printf("\nError");
                ch = fgetc(fin);
                break;'}
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. Anyway, you might be able to obtain something similar with a bit of macro magic, something like boost.PP (I don't know if it is usable in C, though)

Comment: As an alternative, you can manually wire a switch-like structure by declaring an array of 256 pointers to functions (one per possible `char` value) and then call array[ch]()

Comment: it's not even possible to compile.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot use a regex as a case statement in C. In fact, C has no built-in support for any kind of regular expressions at all<sup>*</sup>. However, you can achieve the same result in terms of speed if you "expand" your regular expressions with fall-through:

```
switch (ch) {
    case '"';
    case ';':
    case ',':
    case '(':
    case ')':
    case '{':
    case '}':
    case ' ': printf("\nSEPARATOR: %c found\n", ch);
                                ch =fgetc(fin);
                                break;
    case '_':
    case 'a':
    case 'b':
    ... // The other 24 letters go here
    case 'A':
    case 'B':
    ... // Same thing for uppercase letters
    case 'Z': printf("\nIDENTIFIER: ");
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this would result in much longer code. You can convert it to a lookup table, though, which would be less readable, but run roughly as fast:

```
enum {
    OTHER
,   ID_START
,   DIGIT
,   SEPARATOR
};

int map_char(unsigned char c) {
    static int *lookup_ptr = NULL;
    static int lookup[256];
    if (lookup_ptr == NULL) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i != 256 ; i++) {
            if (i=='"; || i==';' || i==',' || ...) {
                lookup[i] = SEPARATOR;
            } else if (i=='_' || isalpha(i)) {
                lookup[i] = ID_START;
            } else if (isdigit(i)) {
                lookup[i] = DIGIT;
            } else {
                lookup[i] = OTHER;
            }
        }
        lookup_ptr = lookup;
    }
    return lookup_ptr[c];
}
```

Now you can use the function as follows:

```
switch (map_char(ch)) {
    case SEPARATOR:
        ...
        break;
    case ID_START:
        ...
        break;
    case DIGIT:
        ...
        break;
    case OTHER:
        ...
        break;
}
```

<sup>*</sup> Square bracket syntax of `scanf` functions only looks like regex, but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you can only use hard coded strings and constants in switch statements.

So: ***no - it is not impossible***.

Comment: @shekharsuman:  You can typically use 4-character strings, but it is non-portable and generally frowned upon.  Lots of details are implementation dependent.  *Example*  `switch (myText) { case 'open': DoOpen(); break; case 'close': DoClose(); break; case 'stop': DoStop(); break }`

Comment: @abelenky- Thanks,but, I really didn't know that. When was this introduced in C,please let me know. Once again I thank you for providing this information!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. You're putting regexes in character literals, which doesn't make sense, or do anything useful (although for obscure reasons it's not actually illegal).

Since you're only using character classes, the pure C replacement would be

`case '"': case ',': case '(': case ')': ...`

(you can have any number of case labels on a single statement).